# code for login authorization using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs... i need help in writing code for login authorization with encoded credentials.. i need to do what i have done in jquery.
My jquery code is given below. using java rest services and mysql as backend.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){               
    $(".user_login").click(function(){                          
        var username=$('#uname').val();                         
        var password=$('#pass').val();

        function make_base_auth(username, password) {
              var tok = username + ':' + password;
              var hash = btoa(tok);
              return "Basic " + hash;
            }
        $.ajax
          ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "templates/login",
            dataType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization" , make_base_auth(username, password)); 
            },
            success: function(){
                window.location.assign ="welcome.jsp";
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var a = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                $("#login_msg").html("<p style='margin:3px'>" + a.message.text + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });
});    
    </script>
```

Comment: looks pretty straightforward, replace `.click` with `ng-click`, replace `$.ajax`  with `$http`, few other minor changes... what are you having trouble with, *exactly*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<html ng-app="auth">
   <div data-ng-controller="AuthController as vm">

          // your template

      <form>

          <input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.username">
          <input type="password" data-ng-model="vm.password">

         <button data-ng-click="vm.login()">Login</button>
      </form

      // your template
   </div>
</html>
```

JS auth.js

```
  var app = angular.module('auth', []);
  app.controller('AuthController', ['$scope', function($scope){

     var vm = this;

     vm.login = function() {


        function make_base_auth(username, password) {
              var tok = username + ':' + password;
              var hash = btoa(tok);
              return "Basic " + hash;
            }

        // IMPORTANT, you should move request logic to repositores, 
        // controller should only do stuff like:
        // authService.login(vm.username, vm.password).then(...)

        $.ajax
          ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "templates/login",
            dataType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization" , make_base_auth(vm.username, vm.password)); 
            },
            success: function(){
                window.location.assign ="welcome.jsp";
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var a = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                $("#login_msg").html("<p style='margin:3px'>" + a.message.text + "</p>");
            }
        });

     }


  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular Js functionalities and API's while create web app on angularjs.

You can use jquery(include jquery library) and angularjs have some in build j query functionalities.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp', []);
  app.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', 'authService', function($scope, authService){
     var self = this;
     self.login = function() {        
            authService.auth(self.username, self.password).then(function(response){
            self.message = "logged in successfully";
            }, function(error){
            self.message = "auth failed";            
            });        
        }
  }]);
  
  app.service('authService', function($http){  
  this.auth = function(username, pass){
  var postdata = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'templates/login',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data: { 'username': username, 'password':pass }
};
  return $http.post(postdata);
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp">
   <div ng-controller="authCtrl as auth">
      <form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="auth.username">
        <input type="password" ng-model="auth.password">
        <button ng-click="auth.login()">Login</button>
      </form>
      <p style="font-size: 20px;color:red">{{auth.message}}</p>
    
   </div>
</body>
```